# Brightcove pause() not working on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, brightcove

I have created a page with a video and set it up so that if you click to view something else on the page the video pauses. This works great on my desktop, but not on mobile devices like an iPad or my android phone.

Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var player; 
  var videoPlayer;  

  function onTemplateLoaded(experienceId) {
    player = brightcove.getExperience(experienceId);
    videoPlayer = player.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);      
  }
function togglePause() {      
  videoPlayer.pause();      
}
</script>
```

For test purposes I've tossed a button on to the page and onclick it calls the "togglePause" function.

```
<button onclick="togglePause()">PLAY</button>
```

Any idea why this isn't working on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a templateReady handler and move the initialisation of the APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER module to that. This is a really common mistake and using just a templateLoadHandler works most of the time especially on desktop so it catches a lot of people out on mobile.

See the following notes from http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/getting-started-smart-player-api

> Important: understand the difference between the template loaded and
>   template ready events:
>
> - templateLoad: all the data for player and API have been received by
>     the browser, and you can now get references to the overall player (the
>     BrightcoveExperience) — the player has not been fully set up, though,
>     and if you try to invoke any methods on it at this point, you are
>     setting up a racing condition
> - templateReady: the player has now been
>     fully instantiated and is ready to interact with via the API — you
>     should only call methods of the API modules after the template ready
>     event has fired
>
> To avoid calling methods too early, you can skip the
>   templateLoad event and just handle the templateReady event. The
>   disadvantage of this is that the player ID is not passed to
>   templateReady handler, so you will need to get it from the publishing
>   code in order to get a reference to the player.